# NextJS: how to make all core and bundle scripts load asynchronously?

Tags: optimization, next.js, next.js13

I want to make a splash/loader screen in an NextJS app that should appear almost instantly before any NextJS core & bundle scripts finish downloading. Problem is that NextJS making them either synchronous or deferred so I cannot render my custom DOM content while they are downloading and parsing. If the first load JS of the bundle is rather big and Internet is slow, the page stays empty for quite a while.

I know you can set different loading strategies for third-party scripts (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/scripts) like `afterInteractive`. Is there a way to make something similar to `<NextScript />` in `/pages/_document.jsx`? Is it possible to make it async?